# Log controller requests to syslog in tg2

Tags: linux, syslog, turbogears, turbogears2

Is there any built-in automate way to log controller request events to system log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup - it's just Python's standard logger, so it can output to a bunch of different streams.
[I wrote a blog article on understanding the TG2 logger](http://blog.wilcoxd.com/blog/?p=129) that might be helpful.

Comment: Nice and simple (and built-in, of course)! I'll try it out and I'll post my results here.